Prove that Lebesgue Outer Measure is regular
I am following the text, Real Analysis, Bruckner Bruckner and Thomson.
I encounter a problem in the proof of regularity of Lebesgue Outer Measure. The definition of a regular outer measure is given as follows:

An outer measure $\mu^{*}$ on a set $X$ is called regular, if for every $E\subseteq X$ there is a $\mu^*$-measurable set $H$, such that $\mu^{*}(E)=\mu(H)$.


After this, they go on to claim that $\mathcal{U}_{2}\cup\mathcal{U}_{3}\cup\mathcal{U}_{4}$ cover $E\setminus(a,b)$. This is where I can't get my head wrapped around. Can anyone explain why the union covers $E\setminus(a,b)$? Also, why is total length of the intervals in $\mathcal{U}_{1},\mathcal{U}_{2},\mathcal{U}_{3}$ equal to the original sequence?

All the $T_n$ together cover all of $E$, so $\mathcal U_2$ is going to cover all of $E\cap (-\infty, a)$, $\mathcal U_3$ covers all of $E\cap (b, \infty)$ and ${\cal U}_4$ covers $a$ and $b$, in case $E$ includes either of them. Sp yes, their union covers all of $E\setminus(a,b)$.

As for the lengths of intervals, For each $n \in \Bbb N$, $$T_n = \bigg(T_n \cap (-\infty, a]\bigg) \cup \bigg(T_n\cap(a,b)\bigg)\cup\bigg(T_n\cap[b,\infty)\bigg)$$ Each of the interesections will either be an interval or empty (with length $0$). and as they do not overlap, the sum of their lengths is the length of all of $T_n$. The length of an interval does not change when its endpoints are included or excluded, so the fact that $\mathcal U_2, \mathcal U_3$ do not include $a,b$ makes no difference to the sum.
